# Recurring AsyncRequestTimeoutException in Spring Boot Admin log

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

I'm currently running Spring Boot Admin on my local machine for testing purposes and I'm getting the following error nonstop.  The application itself seems to be working fine, but my logs are getting filled with these errors.  I'm not sure why...

```java
 org.springframework.web.context.request.async.AsyncRequestTimeoutException: null
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.TimeoutDeferredResultProcessingInterceptor.handleTimeout(TimeoutDeferredResultProcessingInterceptor.java:42) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.DeferredResultInterceptorChain.triggerAfterTimeout(DeferredResultInterceptorChain.java:75) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager$5.run(WebAsyncManager.java:392) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.onTimeout(StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.java:143) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncListenerWrapper.fireOnTimeout(AsyncListenerWrapper.java:44) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl.timeout(AsyncContextImpl.java:131) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.asyncDispatch(CoyoteAdapter.java:157) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.dispatch(AbstractProcessor.java:228) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:53) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_40]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_40]
```

Comment: An issue has been raised on this:
https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/issues/286.

And here the underlying Spring Issue:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14739

Comment: Thank you for bringing this up.  I guess it will get fixed in the next release.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I also had similar error. try this property in you application.yml

```
spring:
  mvc:
    async:
      request-timeout: -1
```

Comment: Hi @VinodYadav, welcome to Stack Overflow. I've edited your answer to wrap your code in a code tag so that it's easier to read.

Comment: Thanks @Vinod, that worked wonderfully.

A repo example illustrate this problem [https://github.com/dilbertside/compose-spring-boot-admin ]

remove the property and the AsyncRequestTimeoutException reappears.

Comment: Beware of making the async timeout to -1, a few of these types of requests will hold on to a thread / socket and may cause starvation of resources if sufficiently large no. of requests are made.

Comment: This is what would be called "Save the day"

Comment: Thanks a lot. Increasing `spring.mvc.async.request-timeout` helped me. Since external calls were taking longer to respond our service was getting timed out.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively without spring boot, add

```java
    @Override
    public void configureAsyncSupport(AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer) {
        long timeout = 5 * 60 * 1000;// for example 5 minutes
        WebMvcConfigurer.super.configureAsyncSupport(configurer);
        configurer.setDefaultTimeout(timeout);
    }
```

to the configuration class that implements WebMvcConfigurer

Comment: you can also declare the timeout as -1 to cancel timeout

Answer (score 4):

In case of using `ComplatebleFuture<Any>` as return type of `@RestController` function and using Tomcat as backing container.Then is required to register catalina Connector customizer into spring context, which will adjust async connection timeout. Because `org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector` has its own property `protected long asyncTimeout = 30000;` which is used as timeout for async request.

```
@Configuration
class TomcatAsyncConfig {
    @Bean
    fun asyncTimeoutCustomize(): TomcatConnectorCustomizer =
        TomcatConnectorCustomizer { connector -> connector.asyncTimeout = 180000 }
}
```

Modifing values of
`spring.mvc.async.request-timeout: -1`  
or `server.tomcat.connection-timeout` won't do.

Comment: This worked for me, I had similar issue. I returned `Mono<Any>`, `Flux<Any>` in `@RestController` and it did a trick.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of configuring the timeout on application level you can configure the timeout for specific subscription.

```java
    @GetMapping(value = "/subscription")
    public SseEmitter subscription() {
        SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter((long) (60000 * 5));
        return emitter;
    }
```

So in the above excerpt, I gave 5 minutes for this particular connection. Rest of the connections will still use the server default timeout.

Comment: I am using the sse and facing the similiar problem, fixed it by using your answer, seems this question not using sse.

Comment: Super helpful! and easy to implement in case when we have just couple of async methods.