# Stream with Reactive MongoDB and time taking operation is being cancelled

Tags: spring, mongodb, reactive-programming, project-reactor

Problem is somewhere in between Project Reactor and Reactive MongoDB (Spring Data).

When executing a stream that contains (in the following order):

1. Method that operates on *Reactive MongoDB* which is very quick
2. Method that takes more than **30 seconds**

Stream is being **cancelled** (look at the code and logs below)

```
@GetMapping("/test/{msg}")
public Mono<SomeObject> test(@PathVariable String msg) {
    return repository.findByMessage(msg).log("1")
          .map(someObj -> delaySeconds(someObj, 35)).log("2");
}
```

As you can see, after 30 seconds stream is cancelled, but after another 5 seconds (timeout is 35 seconds) there's event *onNext* executed.

```
12:59:18.556 [Thread-9] INFO  com.why.temp.TempController - Saved:SomeObject(id=5b604106ef301746a86665f3, message=WHY)
12:59:18.591 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  1 - | onSubscribe([Fuseable] MonoFlatMap.FlatMapMain)
12:59:18.592 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  2 - | onSubscribe([Fuseable] FluxMapFuseable.MapFuseableSubscriber)
12:59:18.593 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  2 - | request(unbounded)
12:59:18.593 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  1 - | request(unbounded)
12:59:18.612 [Thread-8] INFO  1 - | onNext(SomeObject(id=5b604106ef301746a86665f3, message=WHY))
12:59:49.116 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] INFO  2 - | cancel()
12:59:49.117 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] INFO  1 - | cancel()
12:59:53.612 [Thread-8] INFO  2 - | onNext(SomeObject(id=5b604106ef301746a86665f3, message=WHY))
```

Can you explain me why stream is cancelled and how can I handle this?

Is there any timeout that should be increased or am I using Project Reactor Stream API and MongoDB in a wrong way?

Here is my **MongoDB** Configuration

```
@Bean
public ReactiveMongoTemplate reactiveMongoTemplate() {
    ConnectionString str = new ConnectionString(env.getMongoUri());
    return new ReactiveMongoTemplate(MongoClients.create(str), str.getDatabase());
}
```

Any idea? Please upvote this question if you have a similar problem.

Workaround for this is simple, but not so elegant:

```
@GetMapping("/test/{msg}")
public Mono<SomeObject> test(@PathVariable String msg) {
    SomeObj someObj = repository.findByMessage(msg).block();
    return Mono.just(someObj).log("1")
        .map(someObj -> delaySeconds(someObj, 35)).log("2");
}
```

Comment: Of the top of my head, I'd say that most likely, not all fields of a msg are indexed. This potentially causes a collection scan, which - depending on the size of the collection - may take a very long time.

Comment: In this case, _repository.findByMessage(msg)_  is very quick, but if next step in the stream takes more that 30 seconds (_delaySeconds(someObj, 35) in this case_), all stream is being cancelled. I suppose that some connection expires, which should be closed just after _findByMessage_ operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a similar issue, when reactive operations chain took more than magic 30 seconds. In my case it was the Spring MVC request timeout, here is the slution:

[Recurring AsyncRequestTimeoutException in Spring Boot Admin log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39856198/recurring-asyncrequesttimeoutexception-in-spring-boot-admin-log)

The dafault value of `spring.mvc.async.request-timeout` is 30s.

I believe that it will help :).

Cheers!

Comment: You are right, below configuration in **application.yml** helped:
`spring:mvc:async:request-timeout:180s`